# Only display max/min values on axes in Pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, axis

I have the following function in pgfplots:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}% coordinates
\begin{axis}[xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$, axis lines = center, every axis plot/.append style={ultra thick}, ymin=-1,ymax=7]
\addplot [domain=-3:3, samples=100, color=blue,]{x^2};
\addlegendentry{$y=x^2$}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

This prints out the following:[image]

I'd like to remove the tick labels (but keep the ticks) on everything except the min/max on the axes. So I'd like it to look like this:
[image]

To that end, it'd be nice to be able to label any tick I wanted to while keeping the ticks visible on the non-labelled ones. This seems simple but I can't seem to figure it out. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you already know the values, then you can do it easily. One way is to disable all the ticklabels and then label only required ticks.

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[axis equal,
xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$, axis lines = center, every axis plot/.append style={ultra thick},
xticklabels={},yticklabels={}, % remove ticklabels
xtick distance=1, ytick distance=2, % set the tick distance
extra x ticks={-3,3},extra y ticks={6}, % add required labels
ymin=-1,ymax=7,
]
\addplot [domain=-3:3, samples=100, color=blue,]{x^2};
\addlegendentry{$y=x^2$}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]